# Locally installed jar is not included in my IDEA tomcat deployment

Tags: spring, maven, tomcat, spring-mvc, intellij-idea

My IDEA project compiles and builds just fine when I compile using IntelliJ.

For some reason, when I deploy to tomcat using an exploded-war, 1 jar I have isn't included in the deployment and my spring app fails to load because it can't find the class.

The jar in question is a locally installed maven dependency i.e. on my laptop

Could this be the reason why it is being skipped by IDEA?  It maybe tries to find the jar using maven, but since it is local is can't and skips it?

How can I fix this?

The IDEA project is a maven module and builds fine.

Answer (score 1):

Put that jar into the libs folder of tomcat or embed it into your own jar using maven assembly plugin. https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/descriptor-refs.html

Comment: Why is it getting ignored though?  How to put the jar into the libs for of tomcat?

Comment: Maven manages just the build operation and you are supplying it a pom which does not force it to create a jar where dependencies should be embedded. But as you defined some external libs in your projects pom, it just downloads them and builds your code. It is its default and expected way of working. Otherwise you might get a huge jar if you are using lots of external libs. After deploying your app to tomcat, put those jars into the lib folder of the WEB-INF. Then you can start your application.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand, my pom has the lib/jar defined as a local dependency.  When IDEA deploys to tomcat, what doesn't it include the jar when my code is using it?

Comment: Maven finds and downloads dependencies but compiles your code into its own jar. As you said it does this by reading your pom file. If you do not tell it to do so, it will not put dependencies into your resulting jar. So if you take your generated jar and want to run it somewhere else( as you do by deploying it tomcat) you should be sure that all dependencies are in the classpath. If not you should bring them into classpath, tomcats lib folders are in its classpath. So at  this point you have to choices. Either put them into the lib manually or say your maven to pack dependencies into your jar.

Comment: Ok that makes sense.  But I would have thought my IDE IntelliJ would do that for me for some reason since my pom.xml says this jar is need for compile.  So how do I fix my pom for this to work then?  thanks!

Comment: Read the page at the link that I gave above.